# Infimum of equivalent measures

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose I have a functional of the form
$$
F(\mathbb{P})\triangleq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \int_{\Omega}f(x,\omega)\mathbb{P}(d\omega)m(dx),
$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure.
Is there an infimum-integral interchange/representation theorem that would allow me to rewrite,
$$
\inf_{Q \sim \mathbb{P}}
F(Q)\triangleq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\int_{\Omega} f(x,\omega)m(dx)Q(d\omega)
= 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} g(x) m(dx)
,
$$
where $g(x)$ is an $L^1$ function, wrt the Lebesgue measure $m$?

Comment: I reformulated it in a clearer way.... basically I want to pick a "best" measure